# MathJax render issues in cs.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, bug, mathjax, mac

I see following for this following question - [How to wiggle sort an array in linear time complexity?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125372/how-to-wiggle-sort-an-array-in-linear-time-complexity)

[image: Computer Science SE post showing some missing characters in MathJax]

I checked in incognito mode, in extension free Chrome instance (`Version 119.0.6045.199 (Official Build) (x86_64)`)

It seems ok in Safari.

Comment: Looks like a missing font on your side. What is your OS? Can you check with a different device?

Comment: I am using MacOS. I checked same page on Safari and it is rendered properly on same device.

Comment: On Chrome `119.0.6045.169` on iPad it renders properly but I guess Chrome on iPad uses Safari's engine.

Comment: Fine on Mac, even on outdated Safari 14 & Chrome 116, Mojave. Substitution font shows as STIXNonUnicode, in both.

Comment: Related on MathOverflow Meta: [Did mathcal stop working properly?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5508). Related on Mathematics Meta: [Why using \mathcal command produce a square?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35298). It seems that this problem appears after updating to macOS Ventura.

Comment: Yes, I was on Ventura

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on some of the MathJax and change the *Math Settings* to render as *Common HTML*:

[image: Right-click menu - Math Settings - Math Renderer - Common HTML]